# Focusing on window opened by $window

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to lauch a series of windows from an angular application. I want to be able to offer the user to click on a button on the main page to bring this window back into focus.
Normally I would do this in javascript with something like:

```
//Launch the window
newWindow = window.open("http://test.com",'windowName','_blank');
//Then later, to bring the window back into focus
myWindow.focus();
```

In angular I can launch the window as follows(using the $window service):

$window.open("http://test.com",'newWindow','_blank');

How can I use the $window service to bring this window back into focus?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The same way as it would be done with `window`.

`$window` service [equals to `window`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.6/src/ng/window.js#L45). 
`$window` is preferred over `window` global to make it mockable in tests.

[The reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) states this explicitly:

> A reference to the browser's window object. While window is globally available in JavaScript, it causes testability problems, because it is a global variable. In angular we always refer to it through the $window service, so it may be overridden, removed or mocked for testing.